# Apagar dados de uma table html a partir de outra

Tags: angularjs

No meu programa, eu adiciono um nome de um telefone, marco o checkbox, clico em "Search" e ele me retorna tuplas de dados numa tabela, como mostra a imagem 1.

Porém, na imagem 2, quando clico em "Delete", ele apaga apenas os nomes dos telefones, mas os dados da tabela na ultima consulta ainda continuam. Como posso resolver isso? Já tentei um bocado e não consegui. Desde já agradeço!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <title>app</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/post_list.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/jumbotron-narrow.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <style>
      .container {
          width: 500px;
          text-align: center;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .selected {
          font-size: 16px;
      }
      .bold {
          font-weight: bold;
          text-decoration: underline;
      }
      .distance {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      .btn span.glyphicon {       
        opacity: 0;    
      }
      .btn.active span.glyphicon {    
        opacity: 1;    
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.devices = [];

        $scope.addDevice = function (device) {
            $scope.devices.push(device);
            delete $scope.device;
        };

        $scope.delDevice = function (devices) {
            $scope.devices = devices.filter(function (device){
              if(!device.selected) return device;
            });
        };

        $scope.isDeviceSelected = function (devices) {
            return devices.some(function (device) {
                return device.selected; 
            });
        };

        $scope.listPost = function (devices) {
            $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/getPosts',
              data: {
                device_list: devices
              }
          }).then(function(response) {
              console.log('mm', devices)
              $scope.posts = response.data;
              console.log('mm', response.data);
          }, function(error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
        };

      });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="page-header">
     <h1>Phones Defect</h1>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline" name="deviceform">
          <input type="text" ng-model="device.name" placeholder="Add a Device" ng-required="true">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addDevice(device)" 
          ng-disabled="deviceform.$invalid || devices.length == 5">
            Add
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <table class="distance">
          <thead>
            <th></th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-class="{'selected bold': device.selected}" ng-repeat="device in devices">
              <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="device.selected">
                {{'{{device.name}}'}}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div ng-hide="!isDeviceSelected(devices)">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="listPost(devices)">Search</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delDevice(devices)">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr/>
   <div class="row">
        <table id="post_list" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Select</th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Device</th>
              <th>Component</th>
              <th>Content</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="post in posts" class="selected-{{'{{post.selected}}'}}">
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{'{{post.id}}'}}" ng-model="post.selected"></td>
              <td>{{'{{post.id}}'}}</td>
              <td>{{'{{post.device}}'}}</td>
              <td>{{'{{post.component}}'}}</td>
              <td>{{'{{post.df_content}}'}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
   </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: Imagem 2]

[image: Imagem 1]

Comment: Acho que na função de deletar você tem que atualizar a lista `$scope.posts` novamente, removendo os itens que foram deletados.

Comment: Entendo, mas vc poderia dar um exemplo de como poderia ser isso por favor? Eu sou novo em programação com Angular. Muito obrigado!